# How can I have an anchor link scroll past the anchor?

Tags: css, anchor

How can I make a series of anchors on my pages appear partway down the page instead of at the top? Does something like href="#-100px" exist?

```
<a href="#"Ted>
```

Comment: I don't think so, but you can emulate that with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but you could do this using CSS, defining a negative margin on the  targets, e.g.

```
.target {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/La7V9/1/